# How add tabs programmatically in UITabBarController with swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

How to create programmatically tabs from any class extended by UIViewController:

```
class DashboardTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //here

    }
 ...

}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitabbarcontroller_class/index.html)?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

**UPDATE SWIFT 5**

One example of how to create an `UITabBarController` programmatically could be like this:

First we create the `UIViewControllers` that will be the content for each tab of the tab bar interface. For this example we only create one very simple.

```
class Item1ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        self.title = "item1"
        print("item 1 loaded")
    }
}
```

Now, the `UITabBarController`:

We create the new instances of the `UIViewControllers` that we want to display in the tab bar. Then we create an icon for each instance we have created and then we create an array that contains all `UIViewControllers` that specify the content for each tab of the tab bar interface. **The order of the view controllers in the array corresponds to the display order in the tab bar**.

```
class DashboardTabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let item1 = Item1ViewController()
        let icon1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Title", image: UIImage(named: "someImage.png"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "otherImage.png"))
        item1.tabBarItem = icon1
        let controllers = [item1]  //array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface
        self.viewControllers = controllers
    }

    //Delegate methods
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        print("Should select viewController: \(viewController.title ?? "") ?")
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I made like this, but when tabbarcontroller is loaded it doesn't highlight uitabbaritem icon

Comment: @Alexsander add "self.selectedIndex = 0" at the bottom of viewWillAppear()

Comment: Adding VCs in `ViewDidLoad` also works, I wonder why you preferred to use `viewWillAppear`!

Comment: I have tried same but not showing tab bar. Is there anything other than this which I need to do ? `DashboardTabBarController` -> `viewWillAppear` is not calling.

Comment: Creating the view controllers for the tabs should not be done in `viewWillAppear`. `viewDidLoad` is a much better choice. Also, no need to create new instances of `UITabBarItem`. Each view controller already has one. Just set its properties.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using storyboard for the viewcontrollers then you have to write like this in your tabbarcontroller class.

```
class CustomTabbarController : UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let firstViewController = FirstViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)
        navigationController.title = "First"
        navigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.init(named: "map-icon-1")

       viewControllers = [navigationController]

        if let secondViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController {

            let navgitaionController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController)
            navgitaionController1.title = "Second"
            navgitaionController1.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.init(named: "second-icon-1")
            var array = self.viewControllers
            array?.append(navgitaionController1)
            self.viewControllers = array

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do not set the title property on the navigation controllers. Set the title property of the view controllers. If you want the tabs to have a specific title, set the title of the associated `tabBarItem` (just like for the image).

Answer (score -1):

```
    private lazy var tabbarViewController: UITabBarController = {
            let tabbarViewController = UITabBarController()
            tabbarViewController.setViewControllers([startVC,
                                                     offerVC,
                                                     benefitsVC,
                                                     shopVC,
                                                     recipesVC], animated: true)
            
            return tabbarViewController
        }()

window?.rootViewController = tabbarViewController
```