# TabBarController DidSelectViewController Not called after returning to VC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

In viewDidLoad i have `self.tabBarController.delegate = self;`

Then In

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController
 didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
        static UIViewController *previousController = nil;
        if (previousController == viewController) {
            // the same tab was tapped a second time
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self scrollToTop];
            });
        }
        previousController = viewController;
    }
```

**When I am in the main VC it works fine, but as soon as i tab another tab and come back, it never gets called.**

Comment: make one UITabbarController Class and use it using shared instace object to another view controllers

Comment: Can you further explain how to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850411/how-add-tabs-programmatically-in-uitabbarcontroller-with-swift  - refer this link

Comment: i created a subclass and connected the .h and .m files via storyboard. but when i call shouldSelectViewController, nothing gets called. And i have self.tabBarController setDelegate: self