# Adding tab bar to specific view controller without AppDelegate using swift 3

Tags: swift3, uitabbar

So my app project starts with a login/register screen, once a user logged in, they will then be presented with the view controller with tab bars.

I have been trying to find resources on how to add tab bar to view controllers but most of the information I found was to add the tab bar at AppDelegate, which will add the tab bar to all screens.

I did find this article explaining how to programmatically add tab to a view controller. [How add tabs programmatically in UITabBarController with swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850411/how-add-tabs-programmatically-in-uitabbarcontroller-with-swift)

The problem is not all the view controller will be a tab item. In other words, say I have 8 different view controllers that will have the tab bar, but only 5 of them will be the actual tab items listed.

I am hoping to avoid adding tab bar through storyboard and having to add it to all view controllers.

Can anyone give me some idea on perhaps how I can create a UITabBarController and load it in to specific UIViewController as needed?

Thank you!!