# How can I bring a collectionView back to the top when the tabBar icon for that respective view controller is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, xcode10

I am trying to build a social media app in swift that has a tab bar with 4 icons each connected to a view controller. I want to have the four collection views (that are each associated with a view controller) scroll back to the top when the respective tab bar icon is pressed (Exactly like twitter).

I have the logic for how I want the collection view to come back to the top only if the past tab bar icon was for that respective collection view (this is so that it doesn't just automatically scroll to the top when clicking on the respective tab but needs to be pressed again) I tried to debug my first switch case but have had no luck so I do not have the full code for the other cases yet. What I try to do is reference the correct storyboard, then the correct view controller (in this case `homeViewController`), and finally call that respective collection view and use `setContentOffset` to bring it to the top.

Below I provide my whole `tabBarController` class.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainTabController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var pastTabBar: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.delegate = self


    }


    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

            let tabBarIndex = tabBar.items?.index(of: item)

            if tabBarIndex == pastTabBar {

                switch tabBarIndex {

                case 0:
                    print ("go to top of home")
                    //updateHomeCollection = 1
                    let HomeSB : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
                    let HomeVC = HomeSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as? HomeViewController
                    HomeVC?.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
                case 1:
                    print ("go to top of search")
                case 2:
                    print ("go to top of notifications")

                case 3:
                    print ("go to top of profile")

                default:
                    print ("not working")
                }
            }

        if let tabBarIndex = tabBarIndex {
            pastTabBar = tabBarIndex
        }

        }

}
```

It keeps signal aborting when I click the home tab! It is printing this exact statement:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly
>   unwrapping an Optional value

on this line of code:

```
HomeVC?.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)
```

Comment: `HomeSB.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home") as? HomeViewController` you are instantiating new `HomeViewController` everytime. Hope this helps [UITabBar Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26850411/how-add-tabs-programmatically-in-uitabbarcontroller-with-swift)

Comment: I tried making sense of the resource you provided but I think it's too far from my issue. I went ahead and took out the instantiate line and put HomeViewController() instead of HomeVC but still get the same error

Comment: And I should've mentioned this but all my viewcontrollers and tab bar controller are done with the storyboard. @prex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading `ViewController` is not best way. You have to fetch your desired `ViewController` from `Navigation` like below

```
extension HomeTabVC: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if previousController == viewController {
            if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController, let vc = nav.viewControllers[0] as? FeaturedVC {
                if vc.isViewLoaded && (vc.view.window != nil) {
                    let visibleIndex = vc.collectionFeatured.indexPathsForVisibleItems
                    if visibleIndex.count != 0 {
                        vc.collectionFeatured.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath (item: 0, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            }else if let nav = viewController as? UINavigationController, let vc = nav.viewControllers[0] as? CategoryVC {
                if vc.isViewLoaded && (vc.view.window != nil) {
                    let visibleIndex = vc.collectionViewCategory.indexPathsForVisibleItems
                    if visibleIndex.count != 0 {
                        vc.collectionViewCategory.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath (item: 0, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
                    }
                }
            }else{

            }
        }

        previousController = viewController

    }
}
```

You have to store Selected `ViewController` in variable so when you change `ViewController` from one tab to another it will just change `ViewController` and when you tap same tab again it will scroll you back to top. This is how **iOS** is doing it self in all there application

Comment: sorry are you telling me I should paste this whole extension in my tabController file? @PinkeshGjr

Comment: No you have to change code. You have to added your viewControllers

Comment: Ok thank you, What does CategoryVC variable represent? @PinkeshGjr

Comment: ViewController. It's should be your ViewController where you want to scroll.

Comment: I keep getting the error: "Use of undeclared type" for FeaturedVC and CategoryVC, even when I set it to my homeVC. What should I do about that? @PinkeshGjr

Comment: I have just shred logic now i can't code for you so try changing with your viewController.

Comment: I got it to work, but I still am wondering.. If featuredVC is the VC I want to present, then what is CategoryVC? Is it supposed to be the same? @PinkeshGjr

Comment: I have 2 ViewController in Tab so it's depend on your functionality. If you have 4 tab then there should be more condition